# distinguishing between record changing and data being removed in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using the following code, I'm trying to observe when a record is changed or when it has been deleted.  The absence of a snapshot doesn't seem to indicate deletion though.  Are there any ways to separate these two situations?

```
FireRef.child("dataRecords").child(dataRecord).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.exists() {
        let snapshot = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
        print("record has been modified: \(snapshot)")
    } else {
        print("record has been deleted")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you can find answer in [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data).

```
// Listen for new comments in the Firebase database
    commentsRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
    self.comments.append(snapshot)
    self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.comments.count-1, section: self.kSectionComments)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
})
// Listen for deleted comments in the Firebase database
    commentsRef.observe(.childRemoved, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
    let index = self.indexOfMessage(snapshot)
    self.comments.remove(at: index)
    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: self.kSectionComments)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
})
```

And you can use `commentsRef.observe(.childChanged, .....)` aswell

Comment: got it. I need a second observer. Thanks